# Query in hive to pick second value in col2 for same value in col1

Tags: hive

I need help with the below output. The real table set is bigger but I have simplified it here for better understanding.

Input table:

```
id level
1   L1
2   L1
3   L1
3   L2
4   L2
```

Desired Result:

```
ID Level
1  L1
2  L1
3  L2
4  L2
```

Basically out of `L1` & `L2`, the query should pick L2 if present for the given id and filter out `L1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The condition can be prioritized in `order by` of `row_number` function.

```
select id,level
from (
select id,level,row_number() over(partition by id 
                                  order by case when level='L2' then 1 
                                                when level='L1' then 2 
                                           else 3 end) as rnum
from tbl
) t
where rnum=1
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution, it gave me a way to achieve the expected result.